# Intelligently reducing width of parent element when child text wraps due to max-width

Tags: css

I'm rendering some text inside of a `<div>`. The `width` of the `<div>` is constrained by its parent's `max-width` value. The text wraps because of this constraint.

Given certain sentence lengths the layout of the elements can look very lopsided and poor. This occurs because the `max-width` value is being treated as the `width` when, due to text wrapping, a smaller `width` value would suffice.

Is it possible to explain this to the browser? Possibly with usage of `max-width: min-content` / `max-width: max-content`?

I don't believe it is possible, but I wanted to confirm before abandoning.

For reference, here are two boxes containing text. The first one wraps text in such a way that it has a large amount of free space on the right-hand side. The second box does not have this issue as it does not wrap.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}
.tooltip-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class='tooltip'>
  <span class='tooltip-content'>
    Hello, world. This is a tooltip! It's fancy and word-wraps
  </div>
</div>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<div class='tooltip'>
  <span class='tooltip-content'>
    Hello, world. This is a tooltip! It's fancy, no?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion about this particular quirk over the last few years. [This post](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/30/balancing-text-for-better-readability/) nicely summarizes the problem and traditional approaches to fixing it. Their proposed solution has been implemented by Adobe as a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/balance-text) that might fit your needs. Hopefully this becomes part of the CSS spec in the future!

Comment: Thank you! The article helps a lot. :)